# Python Requests: Where is Crypto.dll?

Tags: python, windows, python-requests, pyopenssl

I am trying to use the Python requests module on Windows with Anaconda. After installing it with pip, attempting to import it fails because asn1crypto is required in the cryptography 2.2.2 module. After installing that with pip, it fails because the crypto library (that'd be crypto.dll on Windows) does not exist. Where the heck does this come from? The way asn1crypto uses it makes it seem like this is libcryptoXXX.dll, but I do not see any circumstance that it would be called crypto.dll. It looks like very old versions of pyOpenSSL (back when it was python-OpenSSL) came with crypto.so for Unix distributions, but I don't know where that came from and don't see any mention of a crypto.dll (and crypto.so was no longer distributed by the version of pyOpenSSL that requests says it requires). So what is this crypto.dll and where can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Setting expectations up front - all I've got to offer is a workaround and notes on my own experience.

I was faced with the same issue with Anaconda on Windows, and after going on a small adventure I simply removed asn1crypto from Anaconda. This raised an issue with a dependent package, so I removed that. 5 or 6 packages later I had a subset of Anaconda where Python code seems to successfully build and run.

My assessment is that this is an issue with Anaconda on Windows, specifically with asn1crypto (why do you expect and need "crypto.dll" on machines that don't have it, and offer no alternative?). I'd love to be wrong and for someone to tell me why.

My small adventure had me fruitlessly looking for the mysterious crypto library. I describe this below.

Looking for the "crypto.dll", I came across some questionable leads before landing [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/946), which suggested I could pick up "libcrypto.dll" as part of an older version of OpenSSH for Windows. Not quite what I was looking for, but worth a try. Didn't work. Tried the 32 bit version (in path via system32) and the 64 bit version (in path via SysWOW64) with no luck. Tried the new and renamed to "libeay32.dll" version from a later release of OpenSSH on Windows. Didn't work. Tried the versions from OpenSSL on Windows (inexplicably [renamed in the other direction](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/1931)). Tried masquerading these dlls as "crypto.dll", which just caused other errors.

Once again, I'd love for a more satisfying answer to exist (hint hint, future readers).

Comment: Thanks for enumerating your tried paths